# In WordPress adding ical event, Received unknown HTTP status

Tags: wordpress, icalendar, caldav, jquery-ajaxq, http-status-code-415

Getting HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type for Adding an iCal event through wordpress-ajax. I already created CAlDAC account in phone,
In localhost its working fine.. but problem is when uploading same code in server.. its not working..

In ajax call, I added dataType : 'html', and also added content-type : charset=utf-8, still not working

```
last request:

PUT /rpc/calendars/mediaj11/calendar~722ea7444446a3a75b6569bfed548525/64534JLAPCHS714589-098679S1343476-4573.ics HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.mediajenie.com:2080
Authorization: Basic bWVkaWFqMTE6a3NRX3g6OC5HNFJR
User-Agent: cURL based CalDAV client
Accept: */*
Content-type: text/calendar; encoding="utf-8"
Depth: 1
Content-Length: 435


last response:

HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 08:24:12 GMT
Server: cPanel
Persistent-Auth: false
Host: mail.mediajenie.com:2080
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 386
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

In localhost its working fine.. and also adding event in phone.. but in server its not working.. so I can't figure out what is the problem.. please help me